# Jest mock private method in then()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jestjs

```
export const get = () => {
    return fetch().then((response) => funcA(response));
};

const funcA = (response) => {
    if (!response.ok) {
        return response.json().then((data) => {
            throw Error(...);
        });
    }
};
```

How can i mock response.json().then() ? I got the error `response.json(...).then is not a function`.
I put the json() in the response i mocked

```
response = { ok: false, json: () => err };
```

Comment: If you're building a mock of the `response`, its `json` method needs to return a *promise*, because that's what the real object returns. Or look at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend#unit-testing-with-mock-httpbackend.

Comment: It's working, thx a lot

Answer (score 0):

`response.json` method should return a promise. E.g.

`index.ts`:

```js
export const funcA = (response) => {
  if (!response.ok) {
    return response.json().then((data) => {
      throw Error(data);
    });
  }
};
```

`index.test.ts`:

```js
import { funcA } from './';

describe('48916842', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    const mResponse = { ok: false, json: jest.fn().mockRejectedValueOnce('custom error') };
    expect(funcA(mResponse)).rejects.toThrowError('custom error');
  });
});
```

unit test result with coverage report:

```sh
 PASS  stackoverflow/48916842/index.test.ts (10.276s)
  48916842
    ✓ should pass (5ms)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |      75 |       50 |      50 |      75 |                   
 index.ts |      75 |       50 |      50 |      75 | 4                 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        11.929s, estimated 12s
```